# Is every simply connected open subset of $\Bbb R^n$ contractible?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

> **Question:** Is every simply connected open subset of $\Bbb R^n$ [contractible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contractible_space)?

I know the result is true for $\Bbb R^2$ because by the [Riemann Mapping Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_mapping_theorem) every simply-connected proper open subset of $\Bbb C$ is biholomorphic to the open disk, which is contractible.

Can we generalize to $\Bbb R^n$?

Comment: We cannot. For $n\geq 3$, spheres are simply connected but not contractible.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom The question asks for an open subset, but you can just consider a tubular neighborhood of the sphere.

Comment: it is contaractible iff all its homotopy groups are trivial....so simple connected ness is not enough ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remove any point from $\Bbb R^n$, $n\geq 3$.  The resulting subspace is open, and has the homotopy type of the sphere, so it is simply connected and not contractible (basically this is the same as taking a tubular neighborhood of the sphere, mentioned by Najib Idrissi).